# iOS 12.2 Flash SMS (class 0) with sender and warning

Tags: ios, sms

We found that since iOS 12.2 if one send Flash SMS (class 0), 
[image: iOS wil show]

Uppers side contains our company's name (we send SMS a lot);
Second looks like iOS warning about SMS sender. How can we manipulate with it? Hide second warning?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would work can you wrap the code like a strand of DNA to hide it and put it back together after you are past what ever you are trying to get by in other words put send in one code with the other in parts and assemble it after just a thought

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).